# What does the following complex equation signifies?

Tags: complex-analysis

The set of complex numbers z satisfying the equation
$(3 + 7i)z + (10 − 2i)\bar{z} + 100 = 0$
represents what?

---

Here is my approach
$(3 + 7i)(x+iy) + (10 − 2i)(x-iy) + 100 = 0$

$13x-9y+5ix-7iy+100=0$

$x(13+5i)+y(-9-7i)+100=0$
Though there are no squared terms hence it can't be any second degree curve like circle, straight line then what is it?

Comment: A point${{{}}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint: From $13x−9y+5ix−7iy+100=0$ you get $13x-9y+100=0$ (real part) and $5x-7y=0$ (imaginary part).